# PDF Printing Error

Tags: pdf

Receiving this error when our servers are trying to create pdf confirmation for event registration.

```
[26-Mar-2018 09:17:54 America/New_York] PHP Fatal error:  Allowed memory size of 268435456 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 222560256 bytes) in /home/nrccshow/public_html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/Error.php on line 560
[27-Mar-2018 08:18:37 America/New_York] PHP Fatal error:  Allowed memory size of 268435456 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 224133120 bytes) in /home/nrccshow/public_html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/Error.php on line 560
[28-Mar-2018 09:00:50 America/New_York] PHP Fatal error:  Allowed memory size of 268435456 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 223608832 bytes) in /home/nrccshow/public_html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/Error.php on line 560
[28-Mar-2018 09:01:11 America/New_York] PHP Fatal error:  Allowed memory size of 268435456 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 224133120 bytes) in /home/nrccshow/public_html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/Error.php on line 560
```

Can you help???

Comment: It's a RAM error but that's an unusually high amount that it's trying to allocate all at once. Is there something unusual about the event, or giant images or something that might make the pdf unusually complicated?

Comment: are you trying to generate a PDF for thousands of contacts?